# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_countries '

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, django-countries

```
import uuid

from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum


from django.conf import settings

from django_countries.fields import CountryField

from product.models import Product, ProductImage
from profiles.models import UserProfile

class Order(models.Model):
    """ create order model"""
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=32,
                                    null=False, editable=False)
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                     null=True, blank=True,
                                     related_name="orders")
    product_images = models.ManyToManyField(ProductImage,`your text` through='OrderLineItem')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=False, blank=False)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length`your text`=10, null=True, blank=False)
    country = models.CountryField(blank_label='Country *', null=False, blank=False)
```

I have installed django countries, freeze requirements.txt  and getting import error as below:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_countries '
```

tried installing all packages and folow django documentation

Answer (score 1):

it's very simple
just install it using below command

```
pip install django-countries-with-calling-codes
```

that's it